# how can I use "Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack" on vc 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have vc++ 2008 
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

on windows7

I downlaod Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack samples but I can't open the project/solution files.
my vc can't open file by extion .vcxproj.

what I need to install to fix the problem?

Comment: You should be able to open Feature Pack samples with this version. Has you tried to open the sln files?

Comment: yes I try. I get this message box: the selected file is a solution file but was create by newer version of this application cannot be opened.

Comment: You've got a version mismatch going here.  A .vcxproj file is a VS2010 C++ project.  You can't open it with VS2008.  You'll need to find VS2008 sample projects.

Comment: file that i download form microsoft is "Visual 2008 feature Pack" this must be suite for visual stdio 2008 no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is regular thing for MS: create confusion (similar to using events instead windows messages).

"Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack" does not mean that this is a package for VS 2008. It means that it was released in the year 2008 and later releases are updated by using VS 2010 0solutions.

You should have all samples available after installing VS 2008 SP1. I am not sure if this set of samples belongs to the default installation settings.

Try running SP1 installation again and see if the option to install samples is available. 
Samples should be included as zip file.

If this does not work, use this link: [use this link:](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5718) to download VS2008 SP1 Sample Library.

You can either use installation package or expand the exe file and extract vc_samples.cab from it. vc_samples.cab contains AllVCLanguageSamples.zip_x86_enu. After extracting it just rename it to a zip.